# Apache Kafka Producer Program is throwing kafka.common.KafkaException, java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException and kafka.common. How to resolve it?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(tweets)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:9092)] failed
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
at com.aail.kafka.KafkaConnection.r(KafkaConnection.java:141)
at com.aail.kafka.Postgresconnection.main(Postgresconnection.java:40)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
... 10 more
```

[2016-02-17 09:02:36,876] ERROR Failed to send requests for topics tweets with correlation ids in [0,32]

How to resolve this issue any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the points below to investigate which you might have already checked into.

Check if the console producer and console consumer are working as expected.Following are the commands after the Zookeeper and Kafka servers are started and topic is been created.

```
    bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
    bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Check if the advertised.host.name is been set to the correct value in server.properties file

Please do let me know if any of these help to solve the issue or if you were able to solve it with some other changes.

Comment: I have checked it but did not find any solution for that -Mehul

Comment: If you can please give me some more information on how are you running kafka and zookeeper and the also kafka version, maybe I can try to reproduce the error

Comment: Presently I am  was using kafka-version:0.8.2 and my Kafka-Producer-Program works fine for 15-20 hours and after that it was Throwing this Exception. I Don't why it is Getting. can you check it once -Mehul

Comment: @syedjameer Further to my checks , I understand that there should be some additional messages with the error which could assist in determining the exact cause. Such as the one described in the kafka jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1494. Additionally How many brokers do you have ? How many replications have you configured for this topic ? You can check the logs (controller & state-change log) refer http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/13abrfj8yv/kafka-cannot-produce-message. You can also check on max msg and repl msg size values.

Comment: Issue was resolved. By giving the Multi-Brokers. previously work with single broker now with three Brokers and the code works fine now